# jquery strange problems with class=hide and white text

Tags: jquery, text

As the title states, Jquery is turning my text white in certain areas of the page. it cant be the  im using to encapsulate the ajax call, because it works fine when im not calling the ajax

Its a bit difficult to post the whole script, because its huge and i dont know where its happening. I have no idea how to debug this using firebug, because i dont know where the problem occurs.

Any help is much appreciated

here is the script i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $.history.init(pageload);   

        $('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

        $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

            var hash = this.href;
            hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
            $.history.load(hash);   

            $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('#body').hide();
            $('.loading').show();

            getPage();

            return false;
        }); 
    });

    function pageload(hash) {
        if (hash) getPage();    
    }

    function getPage() {

hash = document.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
        var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(hash);
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",   
            type: "POST",       
            data: data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  
                $('.loading').hide();               
                $('mytag').html(html);
                $('#body').fadeIn('slow');      

            }       
        });
    }

    </script>
```

cheers ke

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: What does the CSS for the "hide" class look like? That's not anything jQuery itself would know about.

Comment: "I have no idea how to debug this" - start by cutting stuff out that is unrelated yet still reproduces the issue.

Comment: some html might be good to see (with the CSS Pointy asked for :)

Comment: Also: doing effects etc. straight on the `<body>` tag is risky - some stuff like that makes Webkit browsers pretty upset. I'd suggest wrapping your page content in an outermost `<div>` and then operate on that instead of on the `<body>`.

Comment: A link to a live demo of the page/problem would be appreciated too.

Comment: fixed it, that was a real good idea Mark about the cutting out of CSS elements one by one in firebug, i didnt realise you could do that so ive learnt something new as well

thanks for all the replies, and sorry about the vague question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firefox [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) for tracking CSS-Styles and even debugging JavaScript. It allows you to select elements directly from the page and see the CSS inheritance tree from that element, which should it make very easy for you to track down what's happening.

Comment: yep, i am using firebug, but i cannot find where the problem is happening, its v weird, some text in a div above is appearing just fine, but underneath it turns white for some reason...